# JPA/Hibernate присоединить только один выбранный столбец

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, hibernate, jpa

К таблице через @ManyToOne

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "APPLICATION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION", referencedColumnName = "APPLICATION_VERSION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private ApplicationsBodies applicationsBodies;
```

Я присоединяю другую таблицу.

Но из присоединяемой таблицы я хочу присоединить только один столбец.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ApplicationsBodies implements Serializable {

... 

@Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
private Long applicationId;

@Column(name = "APPLICATION_VERSION")
private Long applicationVersion;

//Нужно присоединить только этот столбец
@Lob
@Column(name = "BODY")
private String body;

@Column(name = "ACTIVE_STATE")
private Integer activeState;
```

Как это можно реализовать с помощью JPA / Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию orm предполагает объединение на уровне обьектов в рамках полного их описания - такова изначальная концепция и цена простоты описания. То есть если вам нужен только один столбец - опишите присоединяемую сущность в нужное кол-во столбцов (т.е в один или два). Если вас этот вариант не устраивает, например не хочется урезать сущность потому как в других запросах она нужна целиком, то воспользуйтесь:

1. HQL или Native Query - вы сможете написать селект указав только нужные вам столбцы.
2. Criteria API - используя проекции вы сможете задавать нужный вам набор полей.

Возможно это можно сделать с помощью анотации @Formula, но она будет применяться на любое обращение к сущности.

Comment: Благодарю за краткое и понятное объяснение работы orm при объединении на уровне объектов. Мою проблему решила аннотация @Formula. Т.к. обращение к сущности у меня происходит только с целью загрузки одного этого поля, то для меня это стало наиболее оптимальным решение.